# How to return an arraylist of WebElements using Jquery in selenium web driver

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list=(ArrayList<WebElement>) js.executeScript("return $('input:radio');");
```

I am trying to return a list of elements with input type radio using jQuery in `executeScript` method.

Below is the exception that I get:

> com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using JQuery wrapped in JavaScript inside Java to do this? :)

Have you tried something simple like

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='radio']"));
```